# How should I (know)?

Tags: verbs, questions, ellipsis

**Question:** *Do you know who it could be?*

**Response:** *How the hell should I (know)?*

Would it be natural to leave out (know) in the response?

Comment: Why should I? Why would I?

Comment: If you leave out _know_, you would emphasise the word _should_. With _know_, you would emphasise _I_.

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to in the comments section. It would be perfectly natural to leave out 'know'. On a personal level though, it sounds more natural to keep it in.

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Do you know who it could be?
>
> Response: How the hell should I (know)?

That is not a normal reply to that question. For that reason it isn't natural with or without "know".

The following is correct and "know" is necessary.

*Who is it?*

*How the hell should I know?*

Alternatively

*Do you know who it is?*

*How the hell could I?*